# Unread email in Apple Mail in 10.9.2

Tags: macos, mail.app

I have a very annoying problem with Apple Mail. I have used the app ever since 10.2, until now, which I have for the time being changed over to Unibox, which is very nice, although quite slow.

Anyway. My grief is this, the unread count is very slow to go down. F.ex. now I have 0 unread emails, but the icon on the dock says there are 75 unread.

This hasn't been a problem, until 10.9.1 or thereabout. I have gone in and ran vacuum on the email database, but to no avail.

I could of course delete all accounts, all email, but I can't see that fixing the problem, I have also a more than a few GigaBytes of emails, and some accounts that are no longer active, though the emails are still in the app.

Any help is appreciated. I know this might seem a minor, but having unread count on the icon does bother me and in the folder view. I only want to see the unread count, when there are unread emails. Right clicking on the account/folder and choose mark all as read does nothing, and rightfully it is often greyed out.

And lets not forget that an account might have new email, that is not showing up inside the unified inbox.

Comment: I am not able to extract your question from the text. Does the mail dock icon say the wrong number of unread mails? What is your question?

Comment: Are you aware you can set the unread count for the Dock mail icon for different mail folders? Go to Mail -> Preferences -> General -> Dock unread count

Comment: Yes I was aware of that option. Not just the mail icon that is showing unread count, when there are no messages unread, but also inside the app, showing unread messages when there are none unread. The question is, if I am the only one having this issue, or not

Comment: Try sorting your mail by unread ("Sort by Unread"). This will make any unread emails come to the top. If you still don't see unread emails, try opening your mail service in a browser and search through your inbox for unread messages. It's possible that emails you haven't read in the past are now too old to be seen in Mail

Comment: The problem is, when I have read the last unread email, the counter in the folder view still shows f.ex. 3 unread, and also the dock icon might show another number. Eventually this will update itself. This discrepancy is quite a nuisance.

Comment: In short, the dock icon and the inside apple mail is very slow to mark emails as read, sometimes I even have to mark the email as read.